# ResponseCard in response to Amazon Lex is always required

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to amazon documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html
,when the intent type of dialog is "ElicitIntent", the responsecard and message are optional. 
But when I response (from Amazon lambda) object without ResponseCard, I always get exception that need to require it.

```
func HandleRequest(m model.LexCodeHookRequest) (model.LexCodeHookResponse, error) {
fmt.Println("Already reached the function")
input, _ := json.Marshal(&m)
var res model.LexCodeHookResponse
fmt.Println(string(input))
if m.CurrentIntent.Name == "determineIntent" {
    res = model.LexCodeHookResponse{
        DialogAction: model.DialogAction{
            Type: "ElicitIntent",
            Message: model.Message{
                ContentType: "PlainText",
                Content:     "Hi, thanks for contact us, what can I help you with?",
            },
        },
    }
} else {
    res = model.LexCodeHookResponse{
        DialogAction: model.DialogAction{
            Type: "Delegate",
            Slots: map[string]interface{}{
                "intent": nil,
            },
        },
    }
}

s, _ := json.Marshal(res)
fmt.Printf("Return: %s", string(s))
return res, nil
```

}

and response from lambda function to lex:

```
An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Unrecognized field "ResponseCard" (class ElicitIntentDialogAction), not marked as ignorable at [Source: {"sessionAttributes":null,"dialogAction":{"type":"ElicitIntent","message":{"content":"Hi, thanks for contact us, what can I help you with?","contentType":"PlainText"},"ResponseCard":{"version":0,"genericAttachments":null},"slots":null}}; line: 1, column: 236]
```

Can anyone advise me this case?

Comment: Share your code that you are using in your lambda function and the exact error you are receiving and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @ParrettApps I've just added the source code and the response